# How to determine if a set is dense

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

My question reads:

Which of the following sets are dense? (Take $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $q\in\mathbb{N}$)

($a$) the set of all rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ with $q\leq\ 10$

($b$) the set of all rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ with $q$ a power of 2.

I am not too sure how to go about determining if the set if dense or not. I do know that for a set to be dense there must be an element in this set that can be found between any two real numbers $a<b$.

For the first one I was looking at the fact that fractions would be a part of this set, but I am not sure if noticing this helps me. Then, for the second one, I think once I see a bit of how the first once works I will get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) is not dense, because for example in $(0,1)$ you have only a finite number of rational numbers with denominator less than $10$. So you can find an interval in the gaps, which does not contain any of the aforementioned rational numbers

(b) is dense, because you can make $1/q$ as small as you want. So if you take an interval $(a,b)$ you can find a $q=2^n$ such that $\frac{1}{q}<b-a$. So if you start in the origin and make steps of size $\frac{1}{q}$ towards the interval, you will eventually fall in the interval $(a,b)$. See also [Proving that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152003/proving-that-bbb-q-is-dense-in-bbb-r/2152008#2152008) The idea is the same.

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean by (a) when you say you can find an interval in the gaps that does not contain the rational numbers.

Comment: If $S=\{p/q:q \le 10\}$ is dense (in $\mathbb R$), then $S\cap (0,1)$ has less than $100$ points ($1\le p\le q\le 10$), so it is finite. If $x$ is the smallest (minimum) element of $S\cap (0,1)$, then you may take the interval $(x/3,x/2)$, which is guaranteed not to contain elements of $S$. Contradiction. So $S$ is not dense.

Comment: Then for example could the interval [1/100, 1/1000] be a good counter example for a?

Comment: yes, [1/1000, 1/100] would do.